# How to use a download file spec with Artifactory rest API

Tags: artifactory

I was reading about using file specs to download only specific files from artifactory:
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Using+File+Specs

However the doc only mentions the CLI, and I can't find any information on how to use file spec with the REST API directly.

Basically I want to use the following API endpoint:

`/api/archive/download/`

to download (non-recursively) the contents of a directory, but only specific files within that directory. For example `/my-artifactory-repo/somedir/*.json` to download all the JSON files in that folder (but also eliminating anything under `/my-artifactory-repo/somedir/subdir1/`). I would like to download them all at once rather than making multiple calls to artifactory. From what I understand the best way to do this is with file spec (setting recursive to false and using an AQL query to match the files we want to download). Is there a better way? Is this possible to do with just the REST API?

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** The File Spec is a feature of the JFrog CLI. As that, it is not supported from the server side.

**Why I'd still consider using the JFrog CLI for downloads?**

Behind the scenes, the JFrog CLI builds the File Spec for you to make the command much simpler.
For example, in your case you can avoid configuring the File Spec JSON file by running the following command:

```
jf rt dl "my-artifactory-repo/somedir/*.json" --exclusions "my-artifactory-repo/somedir/subdir1/*"
```

Configuring the JFrog CLI is a one-liner and it allows to make the downloads faster by parallelizing them and splitting big files into chunks. It also avoids downloading existing files.

It is also considered much more secure, as it can automatically generate short times access-tokens and perform checksum verifications.

Read more:

1. [JFrog CLI Documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/JFrog+CLI)
2. [Downloading Files](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-DownloadingFiles)